# Dell Latitude D430 recognizes bootable USB drive, but reboots back to menu when I try to boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, dell, reboot

I have a USB of Lubuntu and Linux Mint.

The Dell Latitude D430 *should* be able to work with either of them. The processor appears to be 64 bit (Core2Duo U7600).

Either distro would be fine for me but neither install. The machine DOES recognize the drive, but when I select install/start depending on the USB, it reboots back into the USB menu. It's in BIOS mode, too, which is all the computer supports. I'm using Rufus. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide specifics as to your release & ISO used.  Lubuntu has used 3 installers which were selected by ISO downloaded & written to installation media; but you've not given any clues as to which you're referring to. Linux Mint however is not Ubuntu & thus off-topic here (see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) as only Ubuntu and *flavors* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic.

Comment: It maybe as simple as you're not removing the thumb-drive post-install, however without specifics as to the installer/system installed (which of the three? however note only `calamares` is currently supported) it may also be a poor choice.  FYI: I used a `motion computing j3400 (c2d-u9400, 4gb, intel mobile 4 series)` for QA-testing which is likely closest to yours, but that was only 1 of 9 c2d & c2q boxes used.

Comment: @guiverc I understood it's rebooting right after selecting Try or Install, meaning that probably it's an hardware problem, the old machine rebooting abnormally under load.

Comment: Maybe it is @ChanganAuto but I'd from experience blame lack of ISO validation & esp. lack of validation of the write to installation media myself (we *tend* see what we experience most ourselves; I write >300 ISOs to thumb-drive a year so get loads of bad-writes) but without basic details such as release & ISO (if release has alternatives) I can't give more.

Comment: Im very new to linux so for Lubuntu I used the 32 bit alternative version thats right near the top of the downloads page on the official website, and just used default rufus settings. It might be the ISO validation tho, i dont remember doing that

Comment: There is no alternative download on the official web site (https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) as that is *out-of-support* so I suspect you went to a 3rd party site (if you searched online; google provides 3 sites for download of Lubuntu but only one is official and that is the site I used.. If unsure which is official don't ask google, but go to ubuntu.com (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) and you'll go to official sites for any Ubuntu flavor. The alternate ISO was provided for boxes with <768MB of RAM   But given I believe you downloaded from a non-Ubuntu/non-Lubuntu site, verify your ISO

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that only days ago reached it's EOL.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses  See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note only supported releases are on-topic here